# How to use barometer to get more accurate altitude data on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, sensors

I heard that since the iPhone 6, iPhones have a barmoter that can help get more accurate altitude readings rather than using the GPS data alone.

How can I utilize this barometer sensor to get a more accurate altitude?  Right now, I'm getting the altitude using this code:

```
// delegate method, constantly read latitutde and longitutde
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let userLocation:CLLocation = locations[0] as CLLocation

    // get the lat/long/alt values
    let alt = userLocation.altitude

    altLabel.text = String(alt)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a new API now available for iOS 15 to get absolute Altitude readings.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion/cmaltimeter/3746858-startabsolutealtitudeupdates

About the relative altitude-readings, you would need to have some quite reliable GPS altitude readings to get a base-offset for the relative readings. We use that in our app and it works quite well.

Answer (score 1):

According to Apple's documentation, you can import Core Motion and use [CMAltimeter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion/cmaltimeter).

Have fun mate =).

Comment: I don't want relative altitude though.  I want the absolute altitude.  Anyway to get that?

Comment: @bakalolo As of right now, it's currently impossible to get the absolute height. Check out this Stackoverflow post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36038491/ios-coremotion-calculating-height-difference